# Getting a jQuery function to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple jQuery function

```
$('#bnAddDegree').click(function () {
    alert("bnAddDegree Loaded");          
});
```

I have broken my site into different pieces based upon what the user clicks.  If they click on a tab in the menu to load a section I call a partial_html page and load the section into the center div.  If I put the code above into the main page load it will not fire.  If I add an external js file and load it when the page loads it will not fire, I think because the elements are not initialized yet.  If I put it into an external js page that is loaded after the partial_html is loaded it will not fire.  If I put it ON the partial_html page with a  tag it DOES fire.  If I put a simple javascript function

```
function testFile() {
    alert("File Loaded");
}
```

In the places that the jQuery code will not fire it works fine.

Is there something special that I'm missing with jQuery?

When I load the javascrip file I use

```
$.getScript("js/biosketch.js")
```

And test it with the simple javascript file and it works fine but not the jQuery call.

Comment: `it will not fire, I think because the elements are not initialized yet` it sounds like you need to add a document.ready event handler around your code: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: add a document ready around the external js file. Just tried it it didn't help

Comment: I think we need more details. Can you add a [mcve] to your question?

Comment: Would this also be a good candidate for event delegation? So get the body (say) to watch for clicks on an element that only comes into being later, perhaps as loaded via your effective lazy-loading. See [jquery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: works only if it is on the partial_html page and with and without the document ready

Comment: @user1314159 - this *smells like* what Vanquished Wombat and JasonB are pointing you towards - "event delegation" / "delegate binding." The jQuery documentation on [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) explains in greater detail.

Comment: event delegation was the answer-- thanks Vanquished Wombat and wahwahwah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use delegated event handlers since you are modifying the DOM dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click', '#bnAddDegree', function () {
    alert("bnAddDegree Loaded");          
});
```

Comment: Perfect-- it works.  I can not load the page dynamically can call the functions.  Thank you.

Comment: I can now load the page